# Node library manager

Tags: node-editor

I'm using blender 2.8,  when I'm the shading editor I can add nodes with the default shortcuts:
shift+A and the choose (always with the shortcuts) the node that I want.
But even if is "quick" is still boring every time do the same process. It would be faster (at least for me) find a way to store the most used nodes in a sort of library.So if i need a simple "bump" node i can drag into the shader editor quickly. Does anyone know an add-on OR a way to do something like that? i know that there're assets manager that manages materials , models and so on, But I've found nothing about nodes
Any help?
Cheers

Comment: This would certainly be nice. Failing all else, you can always save out a separate source file and later append things into your current project as needed. Not ideal, I know.

Comment: Most often it's easiest to simply modify your startup.blend to have a few most often used node groups if appending from a library file is too much. Personally I do both.

Comment: hi, cheers both for the suggestion. :D They are both valuable.